# PowerShell to Remove Site User Permission

Tags: powershell, security

I am looking for some help removing a User Permission from a site using PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  My apologies for not realizing this question was never marked answered.  To clarify the question: I was referring to removing a "User Permission" not an SPUser object from the site.

Comment: Do mean in the sense of "Contribute", "Read" etc....

Comment: remove the user from the site this seems to remove the users from any groups, webs, and list and item permissions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove site permissions for a user, you will have to remove the user from the group to which the user has been given permission to. Sample code would look like this -

```
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("Site URL") 
$web = $site.OpenWeb() 
$oSiteGroup = $web.SiteGroups["Group Name"];
$oUsers = $oSiteGroup.Users
foreach ($oUser in $oUsers) 
{ 
    "Removing user : " + $oUser.Name 
    $oSiteGroup.RemoveUser($oUser) 
}
```

If the user is given permission directly without being added in a gorup, rewrite the above code, search within `$web.users` instead of `$oSiteGroup.Users` and it should work.

Good Luck .

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here for an example

http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/bulk-delete-sharepoint-site-users-with-powershell/